# Returning 100-Continue from PHP/Apache

Tags: php, http, apache2, apache

I'm trying to find a way to prevent a script uploading unnecessary data to a PHP script. I had originally tried to kill the incoming read connection which is obviously against the HTTP protocol and I couldn't make it work but I have been researching alternatives and found that the `100-Continue` status code is exactly what I need. My client should send the required headers and `Expect: 100` header and the server should send back either `100 Continue` or `417 Expectation failed` but it seems from my attempts to make this work that the 100 response is sent back by Apache before PHP has a chance to do any processing. Is there a way to have PHP examine the request headers and send back a `100 Continue` response and continue to process the incoming data? I'm already read the raw data from `php://input`.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it in pure PHP code (which isn't executed until the upload is complete), but you can create a PHP extension. Maybe take a look at the [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) extension which hooks into the upload process.

Comment: Thanks for the link, after looking through the code I think that is the answer.