# Start the PHP script after headers, but before body is received

Tags: php, apache, stream

With PHP and Apache, is it possible to start the PHP script after the headers are received, but before the body is sent ?

I mean kind of this:

```
PUT /sync/testStream.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: test
Content-Length: 500
Content-Type: text/plain

<start the script here>

hello
this is a test
```

The objective is to lock a file during the script (during its upload actually).

I tried to read from php://input, with no success: the script is started only when the whole body is received.

Here is my script:

```
<?php
echo "Hello. Start sending data.";
ob_flush();

$file = fopen('php://input', 'r');
if ($file === false) {
    die("Could not open php://input");
}

while (($line = fgets($file)) !== false) {
    echo $line;
}

echo "Bye";
```

Any hint is welcome !

Comment: Can you clarify your question? PHP is usually started by web server even before headers are sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this question on here before (can't find it right now, but I have) and after much discussion/debate, that conclusion was that No, you can't.

This is because the file upload process and receiving of the body of the request is handled by the overlying web server, and PHP is not fired up until after the request has been fully received/parsed/validated.

One point here is that your script appears to be attempting to establish full-duplex communication over HTTP, which is not possible. HTTP is by it's very nature a half-duplex protocol - it has a request-response architecture and you cannot start sending a response before you have completely received the request, it would be a protocol violation.

If you explain exactly what you are trying to do/why you want to lock a file during upload, maybe we can find an alternative solution.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to create a synchronization mechanism that could be deployed over a simple apache server.
The idea was to lock a file during its upload, to prevent anyone else from breaking someone's upload by uploading the same file, but faster.

Comment: With POST method uploads, you should be abstracting the path of the file on the server from the client - POST method is not idempotent and should be treated as such. Or are you trying to handle PUT method uploads here?

Comment: It's a PUT, in the sense that it is file replacement (new version). And the path of the file cannot be abstracted in my case, as it is
1. the identifier of the file, and 2. a location that was wisely chosen by a human. So yes, I need PUT upload here.

Comment: OK fine - in that case, by the very nature of the fact that you have allowed multiple users to PUT to the same URI, you do run the risk of simultaneous uploads. This won't result in *corrupted* files on the server if you implement locking - only one user will be able to write the file at once - but you do run the risk of having a file uploaded and someone else overwriting it. Whether it happens at the same time is sort of irrelevant.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. The fact is, I'd like to prevent a user from sending a file if it will result in a conflict (typically two users sending to the same file path at the same time), rather than letting him send 20Mb over 3G and then only tell him "hey, it failed". Do you see any way I could achieve this ?

Comment: Well I do understand that desire, but I can't think of a solution using PHP - what web server are you using? There may be an Apache module that will allow it, although one point about it comes back to the half-/full-duplex issue outlined above. You can't send a response before the request has been completely received, the only thing you could "legally" do in the context of HTTP is drop the TCP connection, which PHP definitely has no control over. You could maybe do it with something with an embedded HTTP server but it wouldn't be a graceful fail, the client would just get a socket error.

Comment: Yes, that is totally right, I can't just violate the HTTP protocol to have full duplex. And I doubt closing the socket would be an appropriate solution. Maybe HTTP is not the right solution for two-way sync... Many thanks for your insight!

Comment: @Antoine_935 Thinking about it, there is a provision HTTP/1.1 for this, if the client sends an `Expect: 100-continue` header it allows the server to validate the request based on the headers before the client sends the body of the request. This would allow you do what what you want, but I fear it still does not help you with PHP - it is still not fired up to validate the request. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338864) is heavily related. But you need the client to send the header - which you have no control over.

Comment: If I understand correctly then, the client would send a PUT with headers, expect a 100. When the server sends the 100, the clients continues sending the request (thus there is **only one request**). It looks exactly like what I need. I do have control on the clients, since we'll have to write an API for this. Looks cool, I'll have a deeper look at it right away!

Comment: @Antoine_935 That is correct, basically it is a request that receives 2 responses, one before the body and one after. The first indicates whether full request will be accepted. The other question I linked has a link to a PECL extension that seems to suggest it can handle this process within PHP, although it being PECL it is not very well described/documented - and it does say it will only work with Apache/mod_php/PHP >= 5.2 (it does seem to be currently maintained, the latest release has 5.4 related modifications). I can tell you how to do it in Node.js if that's any help...

Comment: Well yes, an example with Node.js would be really helpful. But maybe we should do it somewhere else (private message, new question, mail...) to avoid polluting this feed ?

Comment: @Antoine_935 I am at work at the moment and don't have the time immediately, although I will have a look at it after work and put a link here to pastebin or something. If you want to have a look at it yourself, it all centres around the [`checkContinue`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_checkcontinue) event.

Comment: Ok I can start working without this snippet: learn more about 100, define algorithms, so don't worry about timing :) Many thanks anyway for your help till now, and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not possible because of PHP isn't aware of any request before the HTTP request is completed. In other words, PHP receives the query after the upload is completed.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executed after whole request.
To achieve this functionality you could write custom apache module.